# Mac OS X - Re-install fresh/clean copy of Apache / PHP / MySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, reinstall

So I use the built in local server on my Mac for building sites, and I was recently trying to install PEAR so that I could use SMTP mail functions, but seemed to have screwed something up, and it is now causing problems with my PHP mySQL connection.

I was wondering, is there an easy way to just re-install a fresh copy of Apache?
I am on a Mac Mini, OS X v10.6.8 Snow Leopard

Comment: You can uninstall packages in PEAR. You can even uninstall pear completely. Maybe this already fixes your problem?

Comment: Well I would like a fresh install. I have added other packages in the past and it would be easiest to just get a "clean start"

Comment: For a clean start why not reinstall your complete OS?

Comment: Because I don't want to lose all my software, files, etc. I just want the web server to be a clean install.

Comment: I too had this exact problem, pear completely foobared lion.  I had to reinstall. I realized this doesn't answer your question, but if your computer can handle it i'd recommend developing off a vm like vbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) - it's basically a virtual environment for your entire Apache / MySQL / PHP installation. - I use it for all my development and never had an issue for it. Plus, it is all contained within one folder in your Applications directory, so upgrading / removing is painless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Mac OS X Mountain Lion on MBP and I faced some problems with apache myself. Out of the blue it stopped working and searched a lot of forums for answers, none of which gave me any.

For this to work you will need the original "httpd-conf" file and the original "httpd-vhosts.conf" file. If you have those all you need to do is replace the "httpd.conf" file as well as the "extras" folder that is found in /etc/apache2. Once you replace them restart your computer. That's it. Hope this helps! :)